# Parsing files in subdirectories

Tags: bash, sh

I´m using Zarafa as groupware ( for testing purpose only ) with XMail Server.
To import the mails to the Zarafa system, they need to be parsed by a binary called "zarafa-dagent".

The folder structure is: `/var/MailRoot/domains/xxxxx.xxx/$user/Maildir/`
These folder have subdirectories `tmp`, `new` and `cur`.

My problem is that I can´t get the script working to parse all emails in 10 or 12 `$userdirs`.

Here is my current script:

```
userlist=`ls /var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/`
filelist="/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/$userlist/Maildir/new/*"

for user in $userlist;
  do
   cd "/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/"$user"/Maildir/new/";
   "/usr/bin/zarafa-dagent $user -f *"
done
```

The script outputs a message about not finding the files to parse.

The zarafa-dagent binary needs 2 arguments: 1 username, -f file_to_parse

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: but when I do a echo ``ls -la``within the script the files for each user are listed.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: It might be better idea to use `cd "/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/"$user"/Maildir/new/" && <operation>` so that operation is not run in case `cd` fails. If the operation is only on files & if you are not sure if userdir will contains only file maybe use `cd "/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/"$user"/Maildir/new/" && find . -type f -exec /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent $user -f {} +`

Comment: Didn´t work, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
userlist=/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/*
#filelist=/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/$userlist/Maildir/new/*

for user in $userlist; do
   cd ${userlist%/*}
   /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent ${userlist##*/} -f *
done
```

`${userlist%/*}` and such are *parameter expansion* from `bash`.

**Some advices**:

- `filelist` variable is never used in your script
- don't parse `ls` output
- read about proper quoting
- globs protected by quotes are not interpolated

Comment: Thanks sputnick, here´s the output: Read error: Is a directory
Read error: Is a directory
Read error: Is a directory
Read error: Is a directory

Answer (score 1):

For one, you have quotes around the line that contains the call to `zarafa-dagent`; I'm surprised it's being executed at all.

The line that defines `filelist` is wrong, but unused.

It looks like `zarafa-dagent` expects a file containing an email, not a list of directories. When the shell expands that command, it will expand to `/usr/bin/zarafa-dagent someuser -f tmp new cur`. But it is expecting only one argument, and it is probably expecting it to be a file, not a directory, based on [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zarafa-dagent).

Comment: Hi, the zarafa-dagent expects this: $username and -f (for_email_file) and filename.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can see, is the call to `zarafa-dagent`. Remove the quotes around the line, this should fix at least one error:

```
/usr/bin/zarafa-dagent $user -f *
```

The line with `filelist` is wrong too, but doesn't matter, since it is never used.

**Edit:** When it processes one email only, then you must loop through all files as @Brian already suggested:

```
for mail in *; do
    /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent $user -f $mail
done
```

Comment: Hm okay, at least he parses 1 of 6 mails for each user.

Comment: userlist=/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/*
#filelist=/var/MailRoot/domains/xxx.xx/$userlist/Maildir/new/*

`for user in $userlist; do
   #cd ${user%/}
   cd $user/Maildir/new/
     for mail in *; do
        /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent ${user##*/} -f $mail
     done
done`

Comment: Click on the small help link at the right side. The code looks fine so far, just try it.